# SDL_RenderDrawLines with a Ghost Line

Tags: c++, sdl, render

I have a simple SDL2 window that i'm trying to draw a path on.

I can click ten times and draw out a line with this code

```
if (button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
{
    if (Path.size() == Clicks) return;
    // Clicks is set by the initializer
    // Path is a vector of SDL_Points
    SDL_Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    Path.push_back(p);
}
SDL_Point *points = new SDL_Point[Clicks];
for (int i = 0; i < Path.size(); i++)
{
    if (i == Clicks) break;
    points[i] = Path[i];
}
SDL_RenderClear(ren);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 255, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderDrawLines(ren, points, Clicks);
```

Which works fine, it allows me to draw a path with no issue, however, it creates a sort of ghost line that flies off the top of the screen.

[Here's a picture of the line.](https://www.anony.ws/i/2016/04/25/ghost.png)

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this line and use SDL_RenderDrawLines? If not what call should I use?

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks more like a problem with the parameters for `SDL_RenderDrawLines()`

Have you checked the size of `points` and the value of `Clicks`?

Comment: Yes, the points incitements every time i click by one and Clicks maintains it's size of 10 which i set during initializing the class.

Comment: Martin, thank you, i started tinkering with it and found that by changing Clicks in RenderDrawLines to vector.size() it fixed it completely!